# Substitute array values into a loop to create new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't program in javascript much so feel free to tell me if this is a crazy idea.

I'd like to take values in an array and build arrays off of those values.  For example, using the "people" array below, I want to create empty arrays "jack_test", "john_test", "mary_test", etc.

```
var people = ["jack","john","mary"];


 for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
  //I'd like to execute code here that would create new arrays like jack_test = [], john_test= [], etc.
 }
```

**UPDATE:**  poor question, sorry about that.  I'm really at a beginners level with this stuff so bear with me.  Let's try a little different scenario (sorry if it strays from original question too much):

Say I have an array like "people", though in reality, it'll be much longer.  Then I have another array that has associated body weights, i.e.

```
var weights = [150,180,120]
```

For each person, I'd like to take their starting weight in the array "weights" and add some constant to it to form variables (or as @Pointy points out, form property names) "jack_weight","john_weight" etc.

If I've set this up wrong in my mind and there's some more efficient method, please let me know.

Comment: Dunno why you want to do it, but you can't exactly replicate `var jack_test = []`, which is locally scoped, but you can do this either globally scoped via the `window` object or locally within any other object, like `window[people[i]+'_test'] = []` and then `console.log(jack_test)` and the others will log the empty arrays.

Comment: What does it mean you want a "jack_test" array? Do you mean you want to declare the variable `jack_test`, and assign it an empty array?

Comment: ^ and why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: You haven't marked an answer accepted. Did either of these answers help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot "construct" variable names in JavaScript<sup>*</sup>, but you *can* construct object property names.

```
var people = ["jack","john","mary"], tests = {};


 for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
  //I'd would like to execute code here that would create new arrays like jack_test = [], john_test= [], etc.
  tests[people[i]] = "something";
 }
```

That will create properties of the "tests" object with names taken from your array. Furthermore, `people[i]` could be any expression, if you wanted to do something like add prefixes to the names.

<sup>*</sup> yes I know, there's `eval()`. *edit* and globals, which are object properties and thus a special case of the above example really, except with additional hazards ("special" global symbols etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly replicate `var jack_test = []`, which is locally scoped, but you can do this either globally scoped via the window object or locally within any other object.

```
var people = ["jack","john","mary"];
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  // assigns the property globally
  window[people[i]+'_test'] = []; 
}
console.log(jack_test); // []
```

This works because in the global scope (i.e. outside of any functions), variables like `var x = 'whatever'` are assigned to window, so these are synonymous:

```
var x = 'whatever';
window.x = 'whatever';
```

Instead of using `window`, you can assign properties dynamically to any object using the same method.

```
var myObj = {};
var myProp = 'foo';
myObj[myProp] = 'foo value';
console.log(myObj.foo); // 'foo value'
```